# Anchors not working and page doesn't move

Tags: wordpress, html, css

Ok, I've spent hours on this and I still can't figure it out. The problem is simple. I made a few simple changes to the site and now the anchors don't work. They only work if the page is reloaded.

www.boldcreative.co.nz

Please let me know if you have any advice/guidance. Thanks in advance.

As you can see in the code below, I've tried to call the anchor through using just the anchor name (eg #about) and using the entire url (eg boldcreative.co.nz/#about). Neither work.

```html
<div class="popup_menu_holder_inner">
    <nav class="popup_menu">
     <ul id="menu-left_menu" class=""><li id="popup-menu-item-21092" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home "><a href="http://boldcreative.co.nz/#top" class=" current "><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li id="popup-menu-item-21093" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom "><a href="#about" class=""><span>About Us</span></a></li>
<li id="popup-menu-item-21095" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home "><a href="http://boldcreative.co.nz/#work" class=" current "><span>Our Work</span></a></li>
<li id="popup-menu-item-21094" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home "><a href="http://boldcreative.co.nz/#team" class=" current "><span>Our Team</span></a></li>
<li id="popup-menu-item-21097" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home "><a href="http://boldcreative.co.nz/#contact" class=" current "><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>    </nav>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please add your code block

Comment: I've added code the code

Comment: You don't have any corresponding `id` elements on the sections. Or they're being removed by some JavaScript. But you've not included any JavaScript or other details in your question, so you'll need to debug it from here.

Comment: there are `id` in the sections `<div data-q_id="#team" class="vc_row wpb_row section vc_row-fluid  grid_section" style="background-color:#f9f9f9; text-align:left;">`

Answer (score 0):

try adding target attribute with self value

```
<a href="http://boldcreative.co.nz/#top" class=" current " target="_self">
```

But this will make the page go to http://boldcreative.co.nz and focus on the div with id top

You need to describe more what you want to do in with your anchor tag.

using `<a href="#top" class=" current ">` should focus/scroll your page to div/element with 'top' as its id.

Comment: it should work like the nav links in the footer work

Comment: then using  #about should be enough. just make sure that the elements/div with those ids actually exists in the same page

Comment: it should, but it doesn't. The elements to exist as the nav in the footer is working. `<div data-q_id="#team" class="vc_row wpb_row section vc_row-fluid  grid_section" style="background-color:#f9f9f9; text-align:left;">`

Comment: try this `<div id="team" class="vc_row wpb_row section vc_row-fluid grid_section" style="background-color:#f9f9f9; text-align:left;">`